# How can the id token be return as part of the custom grant response

Tags: identityserver3

I am using a custom grant on IdentityServer3 to allow for Windows Authentication to flow through from WinForm and WPF apps.  I based my code on WindowsAuthentication plug in for [IdSrv](https://github.com/IdentityServer/WindowsAuthentication) .

What I'm trying to figure out is how can I get the custom grant flow to return the id token.  I'm already getting the access token and the refresh token.

I'm looking to the id token, so I can log the user out, once they are done using the applications.

Thanks

-marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token endpoint will only give you id_token when exchanging the authorization code obtained by using AuthorizationCode flow client throuh OpenID Connect Authorize endpoint. More info in the spec here http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest